# Total no. of six digit integers with the property that every succeeding digit is greater than the preceding digit?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many six-digit integers can be formed having the property that every succeeding digit is greater than the preceding digit??

According to me, since the order of the digits is fixed....all we have to do is choose six distinct digits from the 10 digits we have.....and hence the answer to the above question should be equal to (10 C 6)......but my textbook mentions the answer as (9 C 3).....is my method incorrect?
If yes then please suggest a way to solve.....Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Presumably they don't want you to start with $0$.  thus your method gives $\binom 96$ which is the same as $\binom 93$.

Comment: But they havent given any such condition....I think its a typo....anyways is my solution  correct or can I solve it in another better way?

Comment: Most people would say that $012345$ is not a six digit number.  A six digit number has to be greater than $99999$.  Sorry, I'm with them on this one.

Comment: To your question:  Your method is fine (and i have to think it's optimal).  The only controversy is the definition of a six-digit number.

Comment: Oh!! Got it...thanks!! II misinterpreted the question....and hence my solution includes nos. like 654320.....but the question is actually the other way round....Thanks for pointing out the mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you can start with $0$, then ${{10}\choose{6}}$ is correct, as there are ${{10}\choose{6}}$ distinct digit selections (if the digits aren't distinct, then there is no correct sorting), and each selection has only one possible sorting.

If leading $0$s are not allowed, then the answer is simply ${{9}\choose{6}}$.